# Xamarin sql using left join for an android Tablet app

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

try
{
     var results = db.Query<Xclass>("SELECT X.COL1, X.COL2, " +
         " X.COL3, X.Col4, X.Col5, " +
         " A.Col2, A.COL3, B.Col2, C.Col2 " +
         "FROM  left join Xam X " + 
         "left join TABLE1 A on X.COL1 = A.COL1 " +
         "left join TABLE2 B on X.COL2 = B.COL1 " +
         "left join TABLE3 C on X.COL3 = C.COL1 " +
         "WHERE X.COL1 ='"+ somevalue +"'");
}  
catch (Exception e)
{
 // display message
}
```

XCLASS Contains all the getters and setters.
But it only pulls in the Xam table and not the A, B, or C table values.
I originally had the table name in the Class but took it out to see if that would help. 
Any assistance is appreciated. I am trying to avoid linq but if is necessary I will try it.

Comment: try "A.COL3 as 'MyPropertyName'"

Comment: Not sure what you mean. is it  "A.COL2 as a_col2 , A.COL3 as a_col3 ........"  ?

Comment: "A.COL2 as a_col2 , A.COL3 as a_col3 ........"   That works! unbelievable. Now at this point I have to ask "WHY" but is really not that important. Thanks so much. You are awesome!

Comment: I hope now you also have the answer about "why". Happy programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance(s) of `Xclass` object is created from the results of your query via reflection.
The columns in query's result set are translated to properties of the class
and the setters of hese properties are used to assign their values.
Therefore you must supply some hints to SQlite so it will know which column corresponds to which property. This is done via `as` keyword.
So, if you want assign the value of `A.COL2` column in the result to property named `MyCol2Property` inside `Xclass`, you must retrieve it in the query using the syntax

```
A.Col2 as MyCol2Property
```